# Feature file with scenario outline and quotes in data

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I have Scenario in a feature file where i am given a message to verify with quotes. Please look in the following example:

```
Scenario Outline: Testing xyz
Give you are a valid user 
When you log in to the System as Richard
Then you will be welcomed with "<Msg>"
Examples:
| Msg |
| Welcome to this application "Richard" |
```

Sample stub method for the @Then part:

```
@Then
public void Welcome to this application Richard(String arg){
System.out.println(arg);
}
```

OUTPUT: 
Welcome to this application

Notice that the arg parameter does not contain word "Richard" with quotation. But business rules say the message should have the quotes around the name.

Can any one help me to write the feature file so that i get the word "Richard" in my parameter with the quotes?

I am using Java + Selenium + Cucumber

Comment: Ok. I found a solution. In cucumber file i will put single quotation. So 
    Examples:
    | Msg |
    | Welcome to this application 'Richard' |

And in stub method i will replace all the single code with double quote and then verify.  So
    @Then
    public void Welcome to this application Richard(String arg){
    System.out.println(arg.replace(" ' "," \" ");
    }

Comment: You don't need to use quotes at all :)
<> is enough for Scenario Outline